# How to record editors using arcpy.management.EnableEditorTracking?

Tags: arcpy, editing

I have a script that creates copies of temporary layers into a geodatabase. I want to keep track of who makes edits to the created feature classes.

I have successfully used the `arcpy.management.EnableEditorTracking` as outlined below, but the "Creator" and "Created" field are null within the attribute table.

Is there a way to set them to the person who activated the script?

```
arcpy.management.EnableEditorTracking(searchArea, "Creator", "Created", "Editor", "Edited", "ADD_FIELDS","DATABASE_TIME")
```

Comment: So you want to populate the values in the existing features? That's not really the envisioned workflow.  EET doesn't want to assert that sort of knowledge, but I guess there's no reason you can't use Calculate Field.

Comment: To compliment @Vince, I've always understood that editor tracking is tracking change at the feature level not at the featureclass level.  So copying entire featureclasses is not manipulating features so the tracker will never capture the change.

Comment: Thanks both for your responses. Editor tracking will definitely have a purpose for tracking later changes. I will just look at adding the user name to the credits section to keep track of how created the featureclass